# Solving an ODE with a jump in the source term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am having a difficulty to derive the solution to the ODE
\begin{align*}
Ay'' - By = G(x)
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
G(x) =
\begin{cases}
C \sin (kx) & |kx| < \pi \\
0 & \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
The solution roughly reads
\begin{align*}
y =
\begin{cases}
p(\sin(kx) + kqe^{-\frac{\pi}{kq}} \sinh(\frac{x}{q})) & |kx| < \pi \\
pqk \sinh(\frac{\pi}{kq}) e^{-\frac{|x|}{q}} sgn(x) & \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases} 
\end{align*}
where $p$, $q$ are some constants in terms of $A$ and $B$. I have tried to use Laplace Transform that leads to something resembling the first part of the solution ($|kx| < \pi$), but I cannot obtain anything that looks like the second part (otherwise). I think the given solution should be correct (and physically feasible), but I have no idea how to proceed. I also doubt that if my approach of Laplace Transform is correct, since the initial condition is kind of not given (in hindsight $y(0)=0$, and I try to make my solution physically bounded). I attempt the question by writing $G(x)$ with the help of Heaviside step function and do the transform (and inverse). Any help would be appreciated.

Update: From the book (c > u)
[image: Gill1]
[image: Gill2]
[image: Gill3]

My attempt:
[image: Attempt]

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti But is it possible to do it via Laplace Transform? I want to know why my attempt does not work...

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Yes, I have updated accordingly. May you have a look at my try. Thanks!

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Thank you very much, would you mind posting an answer below so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to simplify notation, I will rewrite your first two equations as
$$
y''-a^2y=C\sin kx\,[1-H(x-\pi/k)], \tag{1}
$$
where $H$ denotes the Heaviside step function. Taking the Laplace transform of both sides, and imposing the condition $y(0)=0$, we obtain
$$
-y'(0)+(s^2-a^2)\mathcal{L}[y]=\frac{Ck}{s^2+k^2}(e^{-\pi s/k}+1), \tag{2}
$$
which yields
$$
\mathcal{L}[y]=\frac{y'(0)}{s^2-a^2}+\frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}
\left(\frac{1}{s^2-a^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+k^2}\right)(e^{-\pi s/k}+1). \tag{3}
$$
Taking the inverse Laplace transform we obtain
\begin{align*}
y(x)=& \left[y'(0)\,\frac{\sinh ax}{a} + \frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}\left(
\frac{\sinh ax}{a}-\frac{\sin kx}{k}\right) \right]H(x) \\
& +\frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}\left[\frac{\sinh a(x-\pi/k)}{a}-\frac{\sin k(x-\pi/k)}{k}\right]
H(x-\pi/k) \\
=&-\frac{C}{a^2+k^2}\,\sin kx\,[H(x)-H(x-\pi/k)] \\
&+\left[y'(0)+\frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}\right]\frac{\sinh ax}{a}\,H(x)
+\frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}\,\frac{\sinh a(x-\pi/k)}{a}\,H(x-\pi/k). \tag{4}
\end{align*}
For $x>\pi/k$ only the last line of $(4)$ contributes to $y(x)$. To
examine its behavior for $x\to\infty$, it is convenient to rewrite it
in terms of exponentials:
\begin{align*}
y(x)|_{x>\pi/k}=&\left[y'(0)+\frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}
\,(1+e^{-\pi a/k})\right]\frac{e^{ax}}{2a} \\
&-\left[y'(0)+\frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}\,
(1+e^{\pi a/k})\right]\frac{e^{-ax}}{2a}.\tag{5}
\end{align*}
For $y(x)$ to be bounded, the coefficient of
$e^{ax}$ in $(5)$ must be $0$, and this condition determines the value
of $y'(0)$:
$$
y'(0)=-\frac{Ck}{a^2+k^2}\,(1+e^{-\pi a/k}). \tag{6}
$$
Combining results $(4)-(6)$ we finally obtain the following expression for $y(x)$:
$$
y(x)=-\frac{C}{a^2+k^2}\times\begin{cases}
\sin kx+(k/a)\,e^{-\pi a/k}\,\sinh ax &\mathrm{if}\,0\leq x<\pi/k, \\
(k/a)\,\sinh(\pi a/k)\,e^{-ax} &\mathrm{if}\,x>\pi/k. \tag{7}
\end{cases}
$$
To obtain $y(x)$ for $x<0$ take the odd extension of $(7)$.